# Making the x, y, x2, y2 axes constrained to the sides the plot area in core-plot

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-plot

Project demonstrating the problem here: http://github.com/danieljfarrell/CorePlotBoxAxis

---

I want make a plot like the following where the we have a "box" axis, i.e. that axes are always on the outer edge of the plot area.

[image: Plot]

Here *x* and *y* axes are the bottom and left edges; *x2* and *y2* are the top and right edges, respectively.

In the past I have done with by setting the `orthogonalCoordinateDecimal` of the axis. However, this requires updating the coordinate manually when the plot ranges change.

Is it possible to implement the box axis with constraints system? I have tried the following and it correctly pins *x,y*. However, *x2* is not visible (presumably it is being pinned somewhere outside of the range) and *y2* has a 1 pixel offset (see below).

I have tried a few variations on the *y2* constraint but nothing seems to help.

```
    CPTXYAxis *x = [self _makeDefaultAxis];
    x.coordinate = CPTCoordinateX;
    x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
    x.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    // ...

    CPTXYAxis *y = [self _makeDefaultAxis];
    y.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignPositive;
    // ...

    CPTXYAxis *y2 = [self _makeDefaultAxis];
    y2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    y2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0.0];
    y2.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
    // ...

    // Problem here ...
    CPTXYAxis *x2 = [self _makeDefaultAxis];
    x2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateX;
    y2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0.0];
    x2.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
```

This code generates the following plot. Any ideas on how to mirror an axis in this way?

[image: Coreplot]

Comment: It's possible you're seeing some rounding errors in the axis position. What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: Hi Eric, I don't have access to the machine right now, but I installed from the master branch a few days ago. Yes, the y2 looks like a rounding error. What about the x2 position with constraints?

Comment: Same thing—the rounded position is outside the plot area so the axis is invisible.

Comment: I think the tic marks should be visible on x2 even if we are off my one pixel (hopefully I have given the tic marks the correct orientation!)

Comment: Here is an example project, https://github.com/danieljfarrell/CorePlotBoxAxis. I have made some comments in the AppDelegate where the plot is setup. Strangely the 1 pixel drawing issue (for the y2 axis) goes away when you change the x2 axis constraint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo in the `x2` setup section. Change

```
y2.axisConstraints = …
```

to

```
x2.axisConstraints = …
```

Comment: The evils of copy and paste... sorry to bother you with that! Thank you so much for taking a look.